# Invalid length parameter -- Contains string search in procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am converting a sample query to a string search procedure.

This sample will search 2 tables and three columns in those tables.

The rows that are being searched can have short content(only a few words), to very large strings(hundreds of words).

Some include html, so I am stripping off the html before the actual search.

In my testing I just hard coded the search then writing the procedure I am getting a error.

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Which is coming from this line

```
,CHARINDEX(@searchString, TextColumn) as SearchPos
```

Which I tried to fix with this

```
,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@searchString, Sample2TextColumn2) - 1, -1), LEN(@searchString)) AS SearchPos
```

Then converting to using a parameter search, the counts also get broken.

I cant figure out if it is because the parameter is nvarchar(300), and is breaking the counts, but they return as 0.

And finally, what I am returning is the beginning of the string where the search was found, the counts or total number of times the search string was found, and the actual spot where the string was found.

Here is the procedure -- I left the hardcoded values so it would execute, but if I replace with @searchString thats when the problems occur

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[procSearch]
(
    @searchString nvarchar(300) = null
)
AS
BEGIN TRY
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET @searchString = UPPER('"' +@searchString+ '*"');
DECLARE
   @searchData TABLE(                 
                  Id int NOT NULL,                              
                  Target nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                  BeginningOfString nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                  SearchPos int not null,
                  Counts int not null,
                      Rank int NOT NULL , 
                      Section nvarchar(100)NOT NULL,
                  NewString nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
                    );

;with CTE as 
    (SELECT       
      a.Sample2Id
     ,dbo.StripHTML(Sample2TextColumn2) as Target
     ,CASE When LEN(Sample2TextColumn2) <= 60
             Then Sample2TextColumn2 
             ELSE LEFT(Sample2TextColumn2, 60) + '...'
          END As BeginningOfString
     ,CHARINDEX('first', Sample2TextColumn2) as SearchPos
     --,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@searchString, Sample2TextColumn2) - 1, -1), LEN(@searchString)) AS SearchPos
     ,(LEN(Sample2TextColumn2) - LEN(REPLACE(Sample2TextColumn2,LTRIM(RTRIM('first')), '')))/LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM('first'))) as Counts
     ,1 AS Rank 
     ,'Section 1' AS Section 
  FROM
       SampleTable2 a
        WHERE CONTAINS((Sample2Text, Sample2TextColumn2) , @searchString)
     )
    ,CTE2 as 
    (SELECT  
      b.Id 
     ,dbo.StripHTML(TextColumn) as Target 
     ,CASE When LEN(TextColumn) <= 60
             Then TextColumn 
             ELSE LEFT(TextColumn, 60) + '...'
          END As BeginningOfString
     ,CHARINDEX('first', TextColumn) as SearchPos
     ,(LEN(TextColumn) - LEN(REPLACE(TextColumn, LTRIM(RTRIM('first')), '')))/LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM('first'))) as Counts
     ,2 AS Rank 
     ,'Section 2' AS Section
  FROM
       SampleTable b
        WHERE CONTAINS(TextColumn , @searchString)
    )
    INSERT INTO @searchData
        select *, case when SearchPos > 60 then substring(Target, SearchPos - 60, 60) + @searchString + 
substring(Target, SearchPos + len(@searchString), 60) else substring(Target, 1, SearchPos-1) + @searchString + substring(Target, SearchPos + len(@searchString), 60)
 end as NewString
from cte 

union all
        select *, case when SearchPos > 60 then substring(Target, SearchPos - 60, 60) + @searchString + 
substring(Target, SearchPos + len(@searchString), 60) else substring(Target, 1, SearchPos-1) + @searchString + substring(Target, SearchPos + len(@searchString), 60)
 end as NewString
from cte2 

Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GetDate() DESC) AS RowId
       , x.* 
       From @searchData x
       order by x.Counts desc
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
          ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
          ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
          ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
          ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
          ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

using this to strip the html

```
ALTER function [dbo].[StripHTML]( @text varchar(max) ) returns varchar(max) as
begin
    declare @textXML xml
    declare @result varchar(max)
    set @textXML = REPLACE( @text, '&', '' );
    with doc(contents) as
    (
        select chunks.chunk.query('.') from @textXML.nodes('/') as chunks(chunk)
    )
    select @result = contents.value('.', 'varchar(max)') from doc
    return @result
end
```

And the sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TextColumn] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SampleTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SampleTable2]    Script Date: 4/13/2014 7:59:48 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable2](
    [Sample2Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sample2Text] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Sample2TextColumn2] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SampleTable2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Sample2Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (1, N'This is the first Test string')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (2, N'This is the second one')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (3, N'This is the first really long string of text that should be included in the result set.')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (4, N'This is the second long string that will not be returned in the result set')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (5, N'This is a really really long result set that should also be first included in the result set.  It has a seperate sentence in it as well.')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (6, N'Now this is a really really first one.   It is so long that I have forgotten how long it really was.   Well it could be really long but first lets do this.  ')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (7, N'<p>Hello, </p>

<p>This is a really long first string with html inside</p>

<p>This is another line </p>

<p>This is a first line</p>

<p>This one is another line that is really really long, first</p>

<p>First, !=First</p>

<p>I want to see if it will find all the first lines.</p>

<p>THIS IS A CAPITAL LETTER LINE, THE LINE WILL SKIP A LINE</p>

<p>HERE IS THE FIRST LINE </p>')
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Id], [TextColumn]) VALUES (8, N'<p>This markup is copies from Microsoft Word Firstly</p>

<p>This Has some tabs.</p>

<p>First I want to know it it can count them.</p>

<p><b>The counts should return 4 firsts first</b></p>

<p>Well Maybe five first.</p>')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable2] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable2] ([Sample2Id], [Sample2Text], [Sample2TextColumn2]) VALUES (1, N'This is the first text string in this table.

First it will find it all.  Maybe it will find a lot more, but I dunno, I am just typing firstly.

This should be found in the wildcard FIRst.  Maybe.  I am not sure.

This is one of the targets (First).

Maybe it will find ‘first’

First!!!!
', N'<p>This is the first text string in this table.</p>

<p>First it will find it all. Maybe it will find a lot more, but I dunno, I am just typing firstly.</p>

<p>This should be found in the wildcard FIRst. Maybe. I am not sure.</p>

<p>This is one of the targets (First).</p>

<p>Maybe it will find ‘first’</p>

<p>First!!!!</p>

<p><br />
</p>

<p><br />
</p>

<p>I just copied this text inside and converted it to html for the column</p>

<p><br />
</p>

<p>It might work, but im still not sure First -- first</p>
')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable2] OFF
```

Comment: I am searching for the string 'first', sry left that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due the expression...

```
substring(Target, 1, SearchPos-1)
```

...in the two `select` statements you `union all` as part of `INSERT INTO @searchData` toward the end of `procSearch`'s implementation.

This is because `SearchPos` is consistently `0` with the code & sample data you provided, and the resulting `-1` `length` arguments passed to `SUBSTRING` predictably yield the error you noted - as [MSDN's SUBSTRING documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) explains:

> If *length* is negative, an error is generated and the statement is terminated.

To see what I mean about the `SearchPos` values, temporarily comment out everything from `INSERT INTO @searchData` to the end of the stored proc, and replace it with `select * from CTE, CTE2`.

Also, the following simple example (with values taken from results of the temporary `select * from CTE, CTE2` that I recommended) distills the problem from all you provided in your question...

```
declare @searchPos int = 0;
declare @target nvarchar(max) = 'This is the first text string in this table.First it will find it all. Maybe it will find a lot more, but I dunno, I am just typing firstly.This should be found in the wildcard FIRst. Maybe. I am not sure.This is one of the targets (First).Maybe it will find ‘first’First!!!!I just copied this text inside and converted it to html for the columnIt might work, but im still not sure First -- first';

select SUBSTRING(@target, 1, @searchPos - 1)
```

...and reproduces the error:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 12
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Note that I replaced all instances of `'first'` with `@searchString` in the `procSearch` implementation you provided *and was* able to reproduce the error.